# Usage of put / insert / bring

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, verbs, differences, word-usage

Which word suits more a context of a music producer motto?

> Let's put/insert/bring the emotion into your video!

Or would you describe it more accurately with another verb?

Comment: Welcome to ELU; I'm sorry to close your first question. I'm afraid you've provided no context here, so it's not possible to give an answer, let alone a definitive one. ("Inserts" does sound rather clinical, though.) "Puts emotion into" and "brings emotion to" are rather different things. What do you want this sentence to actually **mean**?

Comment: I edited the question to reveal the context more. In fact, I wanted to avoid a word that would sound too technically or that has a meaning which cannot be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: "The music breathes emotion into the video" or (albeit slightly different): "The music contributes emotion to the picture"?

Answer (score -1):

Lets *bring* the emotion into your video." Will be better, as it goes with your context. If I'm not wrong "Lets*Indulges* the emotion into your video" also sounds better.